# Filter array elements by nested array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

First, let me say that this question is slightly different to others I've seen regarding nested arrays in `mongo`.

Most of them ask how to get a specific element in a nested array. I want to get all elements of an array that has itself another array containing a given value.

I have documents, that look like this:

```
{
    _id: something,
    value: something,
    items: [{ 
        name: someItem,
        price: somePrice,
        stores:[
            {name: storeName, url: someUrl },
            {name: anotherStoreName, url: someOtherUrl}
        ]
    },
    {
        name: someOtherItem,
        price: someOtherPrice,
        stores:[
            {name: storeName, url: someUrl },
            {name: yetAnotherStoreName, url: someOtherUrl}
        ]
    }]
}
```

What I want is to get only the items elements that have a given store in the stores array.
This is, if I ask `storeName`, I should get both items in the example. But if I ask for `anotherStoreName`, I should only get the first element of the array items.

Searching for similar questions and trying the solutions I can only get the first matching element of items, but I want all the matching elements.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you show us the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [mongo aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to get result in following way.

First use [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to separate array of `items` and then add match condition.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$items"
}, {
    $match: {
    "items.stores.name": "storeName"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
    _id: 0,
    items: "$items"  //you can add multiple fields here
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should use the aggregation framework to unwind elements on the items array and then treat them as individual documents.**

```
db.data.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$items"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            items: "$items"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "items.stores.name": "yetAnotherStoreName"
        }
    }
]);
```

- $project just let you work with the important part of the document.
- This works on the mongoshell be carefully when using your driver.

**The result.**

[image: Result image]